# Magento 2.3.0 - Set up multiple websites, stores, and store views

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.3, home, multi-website

I have used this [guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html) to setup multiple websites, stores, and store views. As follows

**Multiple websites, stores, and store views**

[image]

**Turned on "Add the store code to the base URL"**

[image]

**Set Base URLS**

[image]

Everything works fine except that the default website should have been the **US** shown in the screenshot above, which has a website and store ID of 1.

Now to access the US site you need yo go to xyz.com/us instead of it showing as the base url itself xyz.com

Is there something I'm missing in this setup? Cause the default home page xyz.com is now showing the following error.

**

> Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: The store that was
> requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. in
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:75
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(168):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->get('') #1
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('') #2
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) #3
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
> Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) #4
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores',
> NULL) #5
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores')
>
> ## 6 /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31):
>
> Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #7
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344):
> Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #8
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48):
> Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'The store that ...', Array) #9
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707):
> Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'The store that ...',
> Array) #10
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
> Monolog\Logger->error('The store that ...') #11
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/index.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 12 {main}

**

Comment: Are you using mongo DB in your project ? What is the purpose ?

Comment: I'm not using Mongo DB, I've setup a multi website/store and I want the default website to show correctly.

Comment: please take a look at the store-views again. They naming and the codes are not as the standard expects them

Comment: What is the standard? And where is it mentioned? I'm not sure that it is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error was being caused because of a extension conflict, disabling it, resolved the issue, the extension in question is Mageplaza Seo url (Mageplaza_SeoUrl) in case anyone else runs into this issue.

As for the default website, it switches/redirect to the US store when you click on a category, product or page link.